# Serilog doesn't get Seq configuration from configuration file

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, seq

I'm reading serilog and seq configuration from this configuration file.

```
{
  "clientId": "...",
  "secret": "...",
"Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information",
    "System": "Warning",
    "Hangfire": "Information"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "//tmp//infinitys//logs//qms//log-.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://seq:5341"
    }
  }
],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithMachineName",
    ]
  }
}
```

When i try to set up my logger, It seems that the Seq part is not being read, only the rollign file part is working.

```
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .CreateLogger();
```

If I manually add the seq configuration like this it works:

```
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341").Enrich.WithMachineName().Enrich.WithProperty("ClientId:", config.GetSection("clientId").Value)
            .CreateLogger();
```

problem is I need to have different configuration with different environments.

Am I missing something in the config file?

Comment: Try [enabling the self log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) so that you can get more information in the console about what's going on. Also, please add a `logger.Information("test")` output right after you configure the logger so that we have something to verify it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `Using` portion of the configuration to tell Serilog you are using the Seq Sink.

```
{
  "clientId": "...",
  "secret": "...",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Seq"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Hangfire": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "//tmp//infinitys//logs//qms//log-.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Seq",
        "Args": {
          "serverUrl": "http://seq:5341"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "WithMachineName",
    ]
  }
}
```